# Add child rows to table, bootstrap bootply example

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, parent-child

I'm using a dynamic table example I found [here](http://www.bootply.com/GGAMvot45f). Its basically a table with parent child relationships, so you can click on a row and it will drop down another row. I need to dive one row deeper with this example but I cannot figure it out. Basically I need a parent, child, grandchild relationship with this bootstrap table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <thead>
        <tr><th>Column</th><th>Column</th><th>Column</th><th>Column</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row1" data-target=".row1">
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row1">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row1">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row2" data-target=".row2">
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row2">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>  
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row2">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>  
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should add you answer as an "Answer" so that others know your question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote (in a question edit):

> ANSWER: I figured it out, heres the answer..
>
> ```
>   <tr class="clickable collapse row1" data-toggle="collapse" id="row3" data-target=".row3">
>         <td>- child row</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>  
>         <td>data</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="collapse row3">
>     <td>- child row</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>  
>         <td>data</td>
>     </tr>
> ```
>
> Just replace one of the child rows with this and you can go one level deeper

Comment: ([Answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))